# Iterate through List<Object> given from Value within a Map

Tags: java, list, dictionary, iteration

I am relatively unexperienced using such Java code. For getting forward in my Selenium automation I want to iterate through a Map>.

Right now I try to get near that iteration with the following code:

```
static Map<String, List<WebElement>> map = new Map<String, List<WebElement>>;

for (Map.Entry<String, List<WebElement>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().size(); i++) {
        *need to find code*
    }
}
```

My intention is to iterate through all the WebElements within the Value of one Key within *map*

Will "entry.getValue().size()" get the Size of the List in that case? And how may I get a certain item out of the list in such a case? Any better solutions maybe?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can access both the key and the value from each map entry and do whatever you need.  The key in this case is a string, and its value is a `List<WebElement>`.  Once you have the list in hand, you can access its size and iterate over it.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<WebElement>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    List<WebElement> list = entry.getValue();

    // to iterate over the list, you can try
    for (int i=0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        WebElement we = list.get(i);
        // do something with this web element
    }
}
```

Comment: As the OP is new to Java, I think it may be useful to explain your code.

Comment: @Mistalis Added an explanation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Thank you very much. :) That might do the job! :)

Answer (score 0):

> My intention is to iterate through all the WebElements within the Value of one Key within map

That should be easy enough:

```
for( WebElement element : map.get(key) ) {
  //do whatever is appropriate
}
```

There's one problem with the above: if `get(key)` returns `null` (either the key is not mapped or the map contain's the value `null` for that key) you get a `NullPointerException`. To fix that could first get the map, check if you didn't get `null`, then iterate:

```
List<WebElement> list = map.get(key);
if( list != null ) {
  for( WebElement element : list ) {
    //do whatever is appropriate
  }
}
```

You might also want to have a look at Guava's [`ListMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html), which always will return a collection/list on `get()` and makes handling maps with list values a lot easier.

> Will "entry.getValue().size()" get the Size of the List in that case?

Yes since `entry.getValue()` should return a `List` unless you mapped `null` for the given key. And since you get a `List` the call to `size()` will return the list's size.

> And how may I get a certain item out of the list in such a case?

If you know the index of that element just check whether the list actually contains that index, i.e. whether `index >= 0 && index < list.size()`. Then just get it with `list.get(index)`.

If you don't know the index you need to iterate over the list and inspect each element until you reach the end or found the element you need. Alternatively, if you can sort the list by the property you're checking, you could also use binary search to locate the element, if it exists.

Note, though, that `LinkedList` has linear cost for `get(index)` and thus isn't well suited for getting by index or binary search, at least not if the list contains many elements.

Comment: Thank you very much for that explanation. Espacially regarding the nullpointerexception. I will take that into account! :)